# Write logs in HTML file using GCD doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, grand-central-dispatch

I created an overload method for `NSLog` in order to write all logs in an `HTML` file.

All logs are written in the `HTML` file using `GCD`.

The problem is that lines are sometimes truncated...

Here my code :

Write in log file function :

```
+(void)writeInLogFile:(NSString *)strLog inFolder:(NSString *)folder fileName:(NSString *)fileName extension:(NSString *)extension{
//Create Directory
NSString *path;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:folder];
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])    //Does directory already exists?
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"%d||Create log directory error: %@",LOG_SEVERITY_HIGH, error);
    }
}

NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@",path,fileName,extension];


int nbOfLogFiles = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil] count];


if(nbOfLogFiles <= NB_OF_LOG_FILES_BEFORE_PURGE +1){
    [HandleString createLogFile:filePath andStrLog:strLog];
}
    else{
        [HandleString purgeLogDirectory:path];
        [HandleString createLogFile:filePath andStrLog:strLog];
    }
}
```

That is the result :

And the call (called each time an `NSLog` is executed):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [HandleString writeInLogFile:message];
});
```

That is the result :

[image: A piece of log file]

As you can see, the last line is truncated...

This appens throughout the file.

I tried to run the process on the main thread and it works well without problems.

Another interesting thing when i change the QOS the result isn't the same, for exemple whith priority high, i have more truncated lines.

Edit : The code to write in file :

```
+(void)createLogFile:(NSString*)filePath andStrLog:(NSString*)strLog{
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[strLog dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

Comment: can you pls post what is the expected result?

Comment: Show the code for actually writing to the log file. You seem to have only shown the code for creating and possibly rotating the log file.

Comment: @KenThomases I Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're writing from multiple threads simultaneously. Consider this sequence of events:

- Thread A seeks to end of file
- Thread B seeks to end of file
- Thread B writes its data
- Thread A writes its data

Thread A's data will overwrite Thread B's data. If Thread A's data is longer, then no trace of Thread B's data will be left. If Thread A's data is shorter, then the part of Thread B's data beyond that length will remain.

Swapping the order of the last two steps has a similar problem. And there are, of course, more complicated scenarios with more threads.

One solution is to serialize all accesses to the file, as you've done in your self-answer. Another is to open the file in append-only mode. In this mode, all writes are done at the end of the file. This is enforced by the OS. There's no way for two simultaneous writes to overwrite each other. The current file position of the file handle is irrelevant, so there's no need to seek.

`NSFileHandle` doesn't directly support opening a file in append-only mode. You have to use `open()` to open a file descriptor and then hand that file descriptor off to `NSFileHandle`. (You could also just use `write()` and `close()`, but it's a bit messier.) For example:

```
int fd = open(filePath.fileSystemRepresentation, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (fd < 0)
{
    // handle error
}
NSFileHandle* fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd closeOnDealloc:YES];
[fileHandle writeData:[strLog dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
[fileHandle release]; // Only needed if not using ARC
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly create the log file in this case. The `open()` call will create it if it doesn't exist, because of the `O_CREAT` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Given the phrase "I tried to run the process on the main thread and it works well without problems." I would say that your truncation problem comes from a buffer being closed before completely empty. That does not explain the disparity you might have observed while using high priority (remember that the extra lines might be coincidental until proven otherwise...).

Now, I would recommend you to try a small [sleep](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/index.html) before ending the thread scope...

Comment: I tried something like this : [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5]; inside the dispatch_asynch but it has no enhancing effects...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution a lil bit tricky :

I removed the dispatch_asynch :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [HandleString writeInLogFile:message];
});
```

And in my write in log file function i did :

```
static dispatch_queue_t asyncQueue;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    asyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("asyncQueue", NULL);
});

if(nbOfLogFiles <= NB_OF_LOG_FILES_BEFORE_PURGE +1){
    dispatch_async(asyncQueue, ^{
        [HandleString createLogFile:filePath andStrLog:strLog];
    });
}
else{
    dispatch_async(asyncQueue, ^{
        [HandleString purgeLogDirectory:path];
        [HandleString createLogFile:filePath andStrLog:strLog];
    });

}
```

It could may be help someone.

But i have to know if according to you, it is a good solution?

John